# ERRORSQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql, login

Intento logearme desde mi inicio de login despues de haber registrado el usuario y me aparece este error: ERRORSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

La contraseña establecida es 1234 pero esta codificada.

Cualquier usuario me lo inserta bien.

login.php Aqui tenemos la pagina de logear en la cual os dejo el php:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    Conexion::abrir_conexion();

    $validador = new ValidadorLogin($_POST['email'], $_POST['clave'], Conexion::obtener_conexion());

    if ($validador -> obtener_error() === "" && !is_null($validador -> obtener_usuario())){
       
        echo json_encode($validador -> obtener_usuario());
            ControlSesion::iniciar_sesion(
                $validador -> obtener_usuario()['dni'],
                $validador -> obtener_usuario()['nombre']
            );
            
            Redireccion::redirigir($servidor);
           
    } else {
        echo "inicio sesion fallo";
    }

    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
}

?>


                    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
                            <?php
                                if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
                                    echo "value = '".$_POST['email']."'";
                                }
                            ?>
                        required autofocus>
                        
                        <br>
                        <label for="clave" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="clave" name="clave" id="clave" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                        <br>
```

ValidadorLogin La clase que valida el login:

```
class ValidadorLogin {
    private $usuario;
    private $error;

    public function __construct($email, $clave, $conexion)
    {
        $this -> error = "";

        
            $this -> usuario = RepositorioUsuario::obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email);
            
           
            if(is_null($this -> usuario) || !password_verify($clave, $this -> usuario['password'])){
               
                $this -> error = "Datos incorrectos";
            }
        }
    }
```

Repositorio Usuario Aqui hago una consulta a traves del email para posteriormente ver si coincide estos datos con los introducidos:

```
public static function obtener_usuario_por_email($conexion, $email){
        $usuario = null;

        if(isset($conexion)/*Conexion existe*/){
            try{

                include_once "Usuario.inc.php";
                
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni = :id";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);

                $sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $sentencia -> execute();

                
                $sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');

                
                $allUsers=array();

                
                while ($row = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $allUsers[]=$row;
                }

                $usuario = $allUsers[0];

                
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                print 'ERROR'.$ex -> getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $usuario;
    }
```

Aqui el usuario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código donde realizas la consulta SQL que está fallando? El problema está allí y no en el código que estás compartiendo. Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Añadido. La cosa es que anteriormente si que me dejaba logearme.

Comment: Veo claramente dónde está el error. Redactando la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Has podido comprobar si mi respuesta fue de ayuda? ¿Sigues con algún problema? Déjame un comentario en mi respuesta si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue de ayuda, un despiste que no te das cuenta y te vuelve loco, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que estás recibiendo se produce cuando en una consulta preparada no hay correspondencia entre los marcadores y las variables definidas.

En tu caso, el problema está aquí, no has definido el valor del marcador `:id`:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dni = :id";
$sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$sentencia -> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia -> execute();
```

En el código tienes declarado el uso del marcador `:id` en la consulta preparada, pero en el código tienes definido el marcador `:email` a través de `bindParam()`.

Al modificar el código para que se compruebe un campo diferente al que usabas anteriormente has creado una incoherencia entre marcadores usados y definidos que te ha generado este error.

Ejemplo de código arreglado:

```
<?php
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("
   SELECT *
   FROM usuarios
   WHERE email = :email
");
$sentencia->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sentencia->execute();
```

PD: Para mejorar la lectura y compresión del código te animo a seguir las guías de estilo definidas en [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) (que engloba a PSR-2 y PSR-1).